# How to properly use and understand the call() method while using forEach() method

Tags: javascript, foreach, call, nodelist

Four months into javascript, and I ran into the following code that I can't put in terms of the techniques that I understand.  I was hoping that someone could refactor this code not in order to satisfy what its purpose is, but to put it in terms that I would understand.  Perhaps just explaining how the forEach() works with call().  I understand them separately but not combined.

I have tried to rewrite it without the forEach and call but that defeats my purpose.  I can implement this functionality without these two, but it sure makes the code succinct with them.

```js
let parentElement = document.getElementById("node1");
let array = [];
parentElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active"); // make them all active 
  array.forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("active"); // remove active
  });
  e.target.className = "active"; // set clicked element to active
});
```

```css
.active,
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="node1">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active"); ` doesn't make anything active, it just finds all elements that already have the class `".active"` (which appears to be nothing). So there's a 0 length array called and there's no return from `.forEach()`. Basically, nothing's done with the `.forEach()` until the next time a button is clicked. This code is far from succinct.

Comment: Using  `.forEach().call()` was a necessity before ES6 because a NodeList like `elem` couldn't be directly used as an array. Presently, a NodeList can be directly processed by  `.forEach()` as if it were an array in all modern browsers.

Comment: Maybe do `const arrayForeach = [].forEach; … arrayForeach.call(elems, …);` or `const arrayForeach = Array.prototype.forEach; … arrayForeach.call(elems, …);` to better understand what `array.forEach.call(…)` does

Answer (score 2):

This code pattern is a bit dated.  I'll explain how it works, and then show you a modern method.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active"); // make them all active
```

The value of `elems` at this point is a [**NodeList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).  It is *not* an Array.

Back in the day, you couldn't use `.forEach()` on a NodeList.  Therefore, you needed to borrow that method from Array.  (It was added later, but for this example let's assume it doesn't exist yet.)

```
array.forEach.call(elems, function (el) {…});
```

This line allows you to use `Array.forEach()` over the `elems` NodeList.  You're executing/calling the `array.forEach` function, with `elems` as the "`this`" object for context.

## The Modern Way

These days, you can use [`for … of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which allows you to iterate over iterables like NodeList, Arrays, and many others.

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.active')) {
  el.classList.remove('active');
}
```

I think you'll find this syntax easier to read and understand.

(By the way, have you considered that radio button inputs might fit better for your use in this case?  You can style them to look like buttons.)

Answer (score 1):

We no longer need Array.call.

Also `var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".active"); // make them all active`  does not make all active, but just selects the active ones

All modern browsers can do .forEach on the static (not live) NodeList returned from [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (you need to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to use map and filter line this: `[...elems].map(el => something(el))`)

Here is the more concise modern way to do want you want - note the [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) with the boolean to `force` the class when true

```js
document.getElementById("node1").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
    .forEach(el => el.classList.toggle("active",el === tgt)); 
});
```

```css
.active,
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="node1">
  <button class="btn">1</button>
  <button class="btn">2</button>
</div>
```